# Site Workflow to Move Files to Different Libraries Based on Document Type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have 5 libraries in a site, one is a scanning queue library where documents are scanned into the library and then the file is QA'd and moved to the other libraries based on the "Document Type" field. I am currently doing this by 4 copy workflows triggered by Quick Tasks, so you have to select the document and then click the quick task button.

I would like to go a step further and have the file move by changing the Document type field and then the workflow is trigger by the change. The problem I am having is I dont know how to have the workflow be non-specific to the source library.

I need something like:

`If Current Item:Document Type equals Document Type:Doc1


Then Copy Current Item to Test Lib1


Then Delete Current Item`

I am just not seeing anyway to do it in SPD.

Comment: What do you mean about the workflow being "non-specific" ? I haven't tried this in 2010 but in 2007 the issue was detecting when a field had changed. I had to create a custom workflow action.

Comment: I mean I dont want to type out all the library names in a bunch of "if" "then" statments in multiple workflows.

Comment: I think ErinsMatthew is right I am not seeing a way to define Document Type to a library because Site Workflow doesnt let me chose Document Type column just give me the defaults to chose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a site-wide workflow to accomplish this, but sadly [can't use SharePoint Designer to do so](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263148%28office.14%29#section217).  You can add a new site workflow using Visual Studio 2010.

> SharePoint Designer 2010 does not support creating reusable workflows
>   for sites. Instead, you can use Visual Studio 2010 to create them.

Comment: +1 nice link, I added the relevant text into your answer from the article